B2C MFA url login failed after auth login
We are using c# asp.net MVC 4.8 framework and we implement B2C as our MFA to our existing system. we have a login button from our website that when click it will redirect to the login of MFA. everything works on our local machine or dev machine but when we transfer it to the test server we encountered this problem below.

A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 40.126.14.164:443 Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.  Exception Details: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 40.126.14.164:443  Source Error:  An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  Stack Trace:   [SocketException (0x274c): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 40.126.14.164:443]    System.Net.Sockets.Socket.InternalEndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +7995660    System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +95    System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception) +336  [WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server]    System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +762    System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar) +81  [HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.]    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +32    Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.<SendAndRetryOnNetworkErrorAsync>d__23.MoveNext() +600    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +32    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +62    Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.<GetDocumentAsync>d__22.MoveNext() +514  [IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'https://r*******mfa.b2clogin.com/r*******mfa.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_SMS/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration'.]    Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.<GetDocumentAsync>d__22.MoveNext() +1524    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +32    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +62    Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.<GetAsync>d__3.MoveNext() +394    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +32    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +62    Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.<GetConfigurationAsync>d__17.MoveNext() +1170  [InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://r*******mfa.b2clogin.com/r*******mfa.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_SMS/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration'. Will retry at '9/25/2024 4:41:45 AM +00:00'. Exception: 'System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'https://r*******mfa.b2clogin.com/r*******mfa.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_SMS/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration'. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 40.126.14.164:443    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.InternalEndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)    at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)    at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.<SendAndRetryOnNetworkErrorAsync>d__23.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.<GetDocumentAsync>d__22.MoveNext()    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.<GetDocumentAsync>d__22.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever.<GetAsync>d__3.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.<GetConfigurationAsync>d__17.MoveNext()'.]    Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.<GetConfigurationAsync>d__17.MoveNext() +2575    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +32    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +62    Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect.<ApplyResponseChallengeAsync>d__10.MoveNext() +618    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +32    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +62    Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.<ApplyResponseCoreAsync>d__40.MoveNext() +353    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +32    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +62    Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.<ApplyResponseAsync>d__39.MoveNext() +447    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +32    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +62    Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.<TeardownAsync>d__34.MoveNext() +200    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +32    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +62    Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.<Invoke>d__5.MoveNext() +943    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +32    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +62    Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.<RunApp>d__7.MoveNext() +197    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +32    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +62    Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.<Invoke>d__5.MoveNext() +746    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +32    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +62    Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.<RunApp>d__7.MoveNext() +197    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +32    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +62    Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.<DoFinalWork>d__12.MoveNext() +192    System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +32    Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.StageAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult ar) +118    System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.InvokeEndHandler(IAsyncResult ar) +221    System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.OnAsyncEventCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) +115

this working code when we do it on our local dev machine
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginBo loginBo)
{
    Uri appToB2cUrl;

    string tenant = UriHelpers.GetTenantName();
    string clientId = UriHelpers.GetClientId();
    string policy = UriHelpers.GetPolicy();
    
    Uri siteUri = new Uri(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);         

    string  redirectUri = UriHelpers.GetRedirectUri(siteUri);         
    string authority = $"https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize";
    string scope = Constants.SCOPE;
    string responseType = Constants.RESPONSESTYPE;
    string nonce = Constants.NONCE;
    string prompt = Constants.PROMPT;

    string b2cUrl = $"{authority}?p={policy}&client_id={clientId}&nonce={nonce}&redirect_uri={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(redirectUri)}&scope={scope}&response_type={responseType}&prompt={prompt}";
    appToB2cUrl = new Uri(b2cUrl);

    return Redirect(appToB2cUrl.OriginalString);
}

 [Authorize]
 public async Task<ActionResult> AzureResponse()
 {
     if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
     {
         var claimsIdentity = User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;

         // Extract relevant claims
         string roleClaim = claimsIdentity.FindFirst("extension_UserRole")?.Value;
         string nameClaim = claimsIdentity.FindFirst("extension_UserName")?.Value;
         string newUserClaim = claimsIdentity.FindFirst("newUser")?.Value;
         string customerAccountNumberClaim = claimsIdentity.FindFirst("extension_CustomerAccountNumber")?.Value;
         string emailAddressClaim = claimsIdentity.FindFirst("extension_EmailAddress")?.Value;
         string authority = UriHelpers.GetAuthority();

         //check if username is null. this is for users that been added to the azure b2c but dont have an existing account in CSP
         if (nameClaim == String.Empty || nameClaim == null || roleClaim == String.Empty || roleClaim == null)
         {   
             return RedirectToAction("AzurePrompt", "Error");
         }
         // Store user name in session
         Session["User"] = nameClaim;

         // Check if the user signed up or signed in
         bool isSignUp = newUserClaim != null && bool.Parse(newUserClaim);

         // Optionally handle signup-specific logic
         if (isSignUp)
         {
             UserUpdateModel userUpdateModel = new UserUpdateModel
             {
                 CustomerAccountNumber = customerAccountNumberClaim,
                 EmailAddress = emailAddressClaim,
                 UserName = nameClaim
             };

             bool updateSuccess = await UpdateEmailAndUserNameAsync(userUpdateModel);

         }

         // Route based on user role
         return ManageRoute(nameClaim, roleClaim);
     }

     // If authentication failed or user is not authenticated, redirect to login
     return RedirectToAction("Login");
 }

Inside the https://rmfa.b2clogin.com/rmfa.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_SMS/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration
{
    "issuer": "https://r*******.b2clogin.com/17a5a7a2-cd33-40b6-8b74-b1d14f19a513/v2.0/",
    "authorization_endpoint": "https://r*******.b2clogin.com/r*******.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_sms/oauth2/v2.0/authorize",
    "token_endpoint": "https://r*******.b2clogin.com/r*******.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_sms/oauth2/v2.0/token",
    "end_session_endpoint": "https://r*******.b2clogin.com/r*******.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_sms/oauth2/v2.0/logout",
    "jwks_uri": "https://r*******.b2clogin.com/r*******.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_sms/discovery/v2.0/keys",
    "response_modes_supported": [
        "query",
        "fragment",
        "form_post"
    ],
    "response_types_supported": [
        "code",
        "code id_token",
        "code token",
        "code id_token token",
        "id_token",
        "id_token token",
        "token",
        "token id_token"
    ],
    "scopes_supported": [
        "openid"
    ],
    "subject_types_supported": [
        "pairwise"
    ],
    "id_token_signing_alg_values_supported": [
        "RS256"
    ],
    "token_endpoint_auth_methods_supported": [
        "client_secret_post",
        "client_secret_basic"
    ],
    "claims_supported": [
        "idp",
        "extension_CustomerAccountNumber",
        "emails",
        "family_name",
        "extension_UserRole",
        "oid",
        "sub",
        "extension_UserName",
        "tfp",
        "isForgotPassword",
        "iss",
        "iat",
        "exp",
        "aud",
        "acr",
        "nonce",
        "auth_time"
    ] }


The problem is:
DX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://rmfa.b2clogin.com/rmfa.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_SMS/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration'
Open a browser on your test server and see if you can access this link?
Sounds like you have a firewall rule that's blocking it.

yes  i can access that (the complete url since i add ** on  that one for security reason)  it shows the jason format when accessing.

I also edit the question and add on the bottom part on what is insiide that link
